# using React.DOM in react-native code

Tags: react-native, reactjs-native

I'm just getting started with react-native Android app. I want to use React.DOM instead of using .jsx code.

For example instead of below .jsx syntax, I wanted to use React.DOM wrapper.

```
render: function() {
  return (<View style={styles.container}>
      <Text>
        This is React-Native
      </Text>
    </View>)
}});
```

The moment I added var DOM = require('react-dom') , I started seeing error
**"Requiring unknown module "react/lib/ReactDOM". If you are sure the module is there, try restarting the packager"**

I rebuilt, redeployed, restarted the dev server.. no luck, not sure how to get this package bundled across.. appreciate any suggestions.

Thanks !

Comment: Just a thought, if there was a way to use the react native Webview to work with the react dom.